# Able to remove numbers, but unable to get word count of filenames

Tags: python, txt

I have managed to remove numbers but am still not getting total count against the file name. Here is the code, I am trying to create a csv file with file name and total word count of text files.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
import glob
import os
import re



folderpath = r'C:/Users/haris/Downloads/PDF/txt/'
target_file = r'C:/Users/haris/Downloads/PDF/txt/total.csv'
filepaths  = [os.path.join(folderpath, name) for name in os.listdir(folderpath)]
all_files = []
for path in filepaths:
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        counter = Counter()
        words = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', f.read().lower())
        counter = counter + Counter(words)
        all_files.append(words)
        total = (len(words))
        print(total)
    mycsvfile = open(target_file, 'w')
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('C:/Users/haris/Downloads/PDF/txt'):
        for filename in files:
            print(files)

    import pandas as pd
    dict = {'filename': files, 'total': words}
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
    df.to_csv(target_file) '
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is a little unclear, for example, you match `A-Z` but read file then convert to all lower case. You seem to only read files in one folder, but you use `os.walk` to print files recursively.

The following is tested and can write file's word count in one folder.

```
import os
import re

folderpath = r'C:/Users/haris/Downloads/PDF/txt/'
target_file = r'C:/Users/haris/Downloads/PDF/txt/total.csv'
all_files = [os.path.join(folderpath, name) for name in os.listdir(folderpath)]
words_counts = []
for path in all_files:
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        words = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', f.read())
        words_counts.append(len(words))
# print(all_files)
# print(words_counts)
import pandas as pd

dict = {'filename': all_files, 'total': words_counts}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df.to_csv(target_file)
```